# tensorflow dataset how to form online distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets, sampling

I am trying to build a histogram of my dataset *online* while the samples "x" are being generated so that I can use this histogram to stir the direction of the distribution of samples "y".
Here is a toy example which is not really working:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(10).map(lambda x: x%10)
hs = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.zeros(10), tf.float32) # the histogram
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : proc(x,hs))
```

where the proc function is:

```
def proc(x,hs):  
  y = tf.math.argmin(input = hs)  
  hs = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(hs, [[x]], [1])  # hist[y]+=1
  return x,y
```

As you might expect the variable "hs" ends up not changing (the function just assigns a new object to variable hs).
Is there anyway i could make this work? (I have looked at rejection sampling in dataset but I dont want to even create samples that might need to be later discarded, I like to have an online distribution and generate accordingly).

More information: So the real generator for "x" is not producing uniform distributions (unlike this example). So the goal of this histogram is to help me generate the "y" samples by filling in the lowest frequency bins of x so that in the end the distribution of {x,y} mimic a uniform distribution in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hs` should be part of your dataset, your code is working fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def proc(x, hs):  
  x = (x+1)%10
  hs = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(hs, [[x]], [1])  # hist[y]+=1
  return x, hs
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(10).map(lambda x: x%10)
hs = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.zeros(10), tf.float32) 
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : proc(x,hs))

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

```
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

If you want `hs` as a separate tensor, you could additionally run:

```
hs = tf.convert_to_tensor(list(dataset.map(lambda x, y: y)))
print(hs)
```

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]], shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32)
```

If you just want to update the tensor `hs` based on your `dataset`, try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def proc(ds, hs):
  for x in ds:
    x = (x+1)%10
    hs = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(hs, [[x]], [1])  # hist[y]+=1
  return hs
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(10).map(lambda x: x%10)
hs = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.zeros(10), tf.float32) 
hs = proc(dataset, hs)
print(hs)
```

```
tf.Tensor([1. 0. 0. 0. 3. 1. 3. 1. 0. 1.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

**Update 1**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def proc(x,hs):
  y = tf.math.argmin(input = hs)
  hs.assign(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(hs.value(), [[x]], [1]))  # hist[y]+=1
  return x, y

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(10).map(lambda x: x%10)
hs = tf.Variable(np.zeros(10), tf.int64) # the histogram
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : proc(x, hs))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The first solution would not accumulate the histogram in a single tensor though. The last one would accumulate the values in the histogram but its created after the creation of the dataset. If there was a way to achieve this accumulation while the histogram was being built it would solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: So my goal is to create the distribution as I'm generating samples and use this histogram to guide the generation of samples in the dataset. If we just iterate over the values of the dataset after they have been created then that goal is not achieved.

Comment: Still don't get it, since `hs` does not influence `x` in the function `proc` @JohnVS

Comment: I think my "toy" example was too much toy and not enough "example". So x would depend on hs in fact. So we can think of x as the initial samples of the dataset, and we are generating a second value (lets say y) whose distribution would match the distribution of x. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: No problem.. can you add that part to your code example in your question?

Comment: Done, but not sure if i added any additional clarity. This toy example can be fixed in a different way by first forming x and then y, the problem is in the real application this is an online process and the dataset is being fed by another code.